# Android ImageButton on Widget not working on api level 31+

Tags: java, android, widget, broadcastreceiver

I am developing a service that receives API requests and displays them on a widget like this:

[image]

sorry for the korean, but it is not important.

the problem is, that refresh imagebutton on top-right corner not working on api level 31+.
I am aware that I need to add the mutable flag for API level 31+ because I have been using PendingIntent previously.

so I tried:
add FLAG_MUTABLE.
add android:exported="true" on AndroidManifest.
update gradle version and library version

and it is still not working. HOW can i fix it?

here is my code:

AndroidManifest.xml

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<manifest xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    package="com.shin.dnfauctionwidget">

    <uses-permission android:name="android.permission.INTERNET" />
    <uses-permission android:name="com.google.android.gms.permission.AD_ID"/>

    <application
        android:allowBackup="true"
        android:icon="@mipmap/ic_launcher"
        android:label="@string/app_name"
        android:roundIcon="@mipmap/ic_launcher_round"
        android:supportsRtl="true"
        android:theme="@style/Theme.DNFAuctionWidget">
        <activity android:name=".SearchResultActivity"/>

        <receiver android:name=".AuctionWidget"
            android:exported="true"
            android:enabled="true">
            <intent-filter>
                <action android:name="android.appwidget.action.APPWIDGET_UPDATE" />
            </intent-filter>

            <meta-data
                android:name="android.appwidget.provider"
                android:resource="@xml/auction_widget_info"/>
        </receiver>
        <meta-data
            android:name="com.google.android.gms.ads.APPLICATION_ID"
            android:value="ca-app-pub-6134407886790967~8924562234"/>

        <activity
            android:name=".MainActivity"
            android:theme="@style/Theme.DNFAuctionWidget"
            android:exported="true">
            <intent-filter>
                <action android:name="android.intent.action.MAIN" />

                <category android:name="android.intent.category.LAUNCHER" />
            </intent-filter>
        </activity>
    </application>

</manifest>
```

part of onUpdate and global variable

```
private static final String ACTION_REFRESH_CLICK = "android.appwidget.action.APPWIDGET_UPDATE";

public void onUpdate(Context context, AppWidgetManager appWidgetManager, int[] appWidgetIds) {
        for (int appWidgetId : appWidgetIds) {

            //do something

            // set a listener to ImageButton
            Intent intent = new Intent(ACTION_REFRESH_CLICK);
            intent.putExtra(AppWidgetManager.EXTRA_APPWIDGET_ID, appWidgetId);
            PendingIntent pendingIntent = PendingIntent.getBroadcast(context, 0, intent, PendingIntent.FLAG_UPDATE_CURRENT | PendingIntent.FLAG_MUTABLE);
            remoteViews.setOnClickPendingIntent(R.id.refresh_button, pendingIntent);

            //do something
        }
    }
```

onReceive

```
@Override
    public void onReceive(Context context, Intent intent) {
        super.onReceive(context, intent);

        Log.d("Clicked", "Clicked");

        if (intent.getAction().equals(ACTION_REFRESH_CLICK)) {
            // when ImageButton clicked
            int appWidgetId = intent.getIntExtra(AppWidgetManager.EXTRA_APPWIDGET_ID, AppWidgetManager.INVALID_APPWIDGET_ID);
            if (appWidgetId != AppWidgetManager.INVALID_APPWIDGET_ID) {
                performApiRequest(context, appWidgetId);
            }
        }
    }
```

and I don't think api request function is wrong, but here is the code:

```
private void performApiRequest(Context context, int appWidgetId) {
        Log.d("refresh", "refresh");
        String encodeItemName = "";
        try {
            encodeItemName = URLEncoder.encode(getItemName(context), "UTF-8");
        } catch (UnsupportedEncodingException e) {
            e.printStackTrace();
        }
        String itemName = getItemName(context);
        String apiKey = context.getString(R.string.api_Key);

        // API 요청
        String requestURL1 = "https://api.neople.co.kr/df/items?itemName=";
        String finalURL1 = requestURL1 + encodeItemName + "&apikey=" + apiKey;
        JsonObjectRequest jsonObjectRequest1 = new JsonObjectRequest(Request.Method.GET, finalURL1, null,
                new Response.Listener<JSONObject>() {
                    @Override
                    public void onResponse(JSONObject response) {
                        try {
                            // JSON 데이터 파싱
                            JSONArray rowsArray = response.getJSONArray("rows");
                            JSONObject firstRow = rowsArray.getJSONObject(0);

                            String itemID = firstRow.getString("itemId");

                            // Glide를 사용하여 이미지 로드
                            GlideApp.with(context)
                                    .asBitmap()
                                    .load("https://img-api.neople.co.kr/df/items/" + itemID)
                                    .into(new CustomTarget<Bitmap>() {
                                        @Override
                                        public void onResourceReady(@NonNull Bitmap resource, @Nullable Transition<? super Bitmap> transition) {
                                            // 비트맵 이미지를 RemoteViews에 설정
                                            RemoteViews remoteViews = new RemoteViews(context.getPackageName(), R.layout.auction_widget);
                                            remoteViews.setImageViewBitmap(R.id.item_image, resource);
                                            remoteViews.setTextViewText(R.id.item_name, itemName);

                                            // 위젯 업데이트
                                            AppWidgetManager appWidgetManager = AppWidgetManager.getInstance(context);
                                            appWidgetManager.updateAppWidget(appWidgetId, remoteViews);
                                        }

                                        @Override
                                        public void onLoadCleared(@Nullable Drawable placeholder) {
                                            // 이미지 로드가 취소되거나 삭제된 경우 처리할 내용
                                        }
                                    });
                        } catch (JSONException e) {
                            e.printStackTrace();
                            Toast.makeText(context, "JSON Parsing Error", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
                        }
                    }
                },
                new Response.ErrorListener() {
                    @Override
                    public void onErrorResponse(VolleyError error) {
                        Toast.makeText(context, "API Request Error", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
                    }
                });

        String requestURL2 = "https://api.neople.co.kr/df/auction?&limit=400&sort=unitPrice:asc&itemName=";
        String finalURL2 = requestURL2 + encodeItemName + "&apikey=" + apiKey;
        JsonObjectRequest jsonObjectRequest2 = new JsonObjectRequest(Request.Method.GET, finalURL2, null,
                new Response.Listener<JSONObject>() {
                    @Override
                    public void onResponse(JSONObject response) {
                        try {
                            // JSON 데이터 파싱
                            JSONArray rowsArray = response.getJSONArray("rows");
                            if(rowsArray.length() != 0) {
                                JSONObject firstRow = rowsArray.getJSONObject(0);

                                Integer unitPrice = firstRow.getInt("unitPrice");
                                Integer avgPrice = firstRow.getInt("averagePrice");
                                NumberFormat numberFormat = new DecimalFormat("#,###");

                                Log.d("price", unitPrice.toString());
                                Log.d("price", avgPrice.toString());

                                // 위젯에 텍스트 설정
                                RemoteViews remoteViews = new RemoteViews(context.getPackageName(), R.layout.auction_widget);
                                remoteViews.setTextViewText(R.id.auction_minPrice, numberFormat.format(unitPrice));
                                remoteViews.setTextViewText(R.id.auction_avgPrice, numberFormat.format(avgPrice));

                                // 위젯 업데이트
                                AppWidgetManager appWidgetManager = AppWidgetManager.getInstance(context);
                                appWidgetManager.updateAppWidget(appWidgetId, remoteViews);
                            } else {
                                // 위젯에 텍스트 설정
                                RemoteViews remoteViews = new RemoteViews(context.getPackageName(), R.layout.auction_widget);
                                remoteViews.setTextViewText(R.id.auction_minPrice, "0");
                                remoteViews.setTextViewText(R.id.auction_avgPrice, "0");

                                // 위젯 업데이트
                                AppWidgetManager appWidgetManager = AppWidgetManager.getInstance(context);
                                appWidgetManager.updateAppWidget(appWidgetId, remoteViews);
                            }
                        } catch (JSONException e) {
                            e.printStackTrace();
                            Toast.makeText(context, "JSON Parsing Error", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
                        }
                    }
                },
                new Response.ErrorListener() {
                    @Override
                    public void onErrorResponse(VolleyError error) {
                        Toast.makeText(context, "API Request Error", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
                    }
                });
        RequestQueue requestQueue = Volley.newRequestQueue(context);
        requestQueue.add(jsonObjectRequest1);
        requestQueue.add(jsonObjectRequest2);
    }
```